# How to determine the weight underwater?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, water, buoyancy, fluid-statics

My body weight is about 85-90 kg and I take a deep breath so my lungs with be full of oxygen. In a swimmingpool I need to hold myself down on the bottom without going up to the surface (I will solve a cube underwater).

I will use 2 hand weights - one for each leg to hold me down.

I need to know how how many kg there should be on the hand weight to hold me down.

Is for example 5 kg on each handweight (ie 10 kg in total) enough?

Comment: You need to use a dive weight calculator of this type: http://www.divebuddy.com/calculator/weight.aspx

Comment: Ask this from Archimedes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes), he does reply you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***average*** density of the human body is around $965 \text{ kg/m}^3$, varying with body type and state of inhalation among other factors.

So your 87 kg will occupy 90.2 litres and displace 90.2 kg of fresh water.  So you'll need about $3.2$ kg of weights for neutral buoyancy (don't forget the buoyancy of the submerged weights!) So you're estimate of $10$ kg should keep you securely on the bottom.

Factors that could change this:  lean body type (less added weight), sea water pool (more weight); recent meal of beans (more weight; Google "German swimmers injected air").

Think carefully about a quick release mechanism, or a dive rope you could climb, in case the cube takes longer to solve than you think.

Answer (score 1):

I am 159 lbs. male with approximate 30% fat index. Kind of a normal to fit man. If I inhale to maximum of my lungs capacity of 5 liters I can barely stay afloat by tilting my head up. My body density is a bit more then 1 kg/ liters.

Buoyancy has to do with many factors:

How fat you are, fat floats.
How much gas is in your intestines. Normal range is about 100 ml to 3 liters
How much air you are holding in your lungs, normal lungs can expand to 4-5 liters, athletes more.
if you expands you chest under the water while holding your breath, like divers do when they want to rise back up.

By just changing lungs capacity by 3 liters one changes their density by up to 5%.

we ignore the buoyancy your body has in the air because it is in the order of .001 of water.

My guess it you need much less then 10 kg weight, may be 2 kg on each leg, so that you don't have to work too hard trying to come back up! Don't forget the rope.

Answer (score 1):

I am a normally fit man weighing about 180 lbs.  A couple of years ago I needed to repair a few leaks in a swimming pool (deep end).   I found that I could easily go to the bottom if I exhaled completely, but couldn't stay down long enough to do the repairs.  I strapped on a set of ankle weights (total 5 lbs, just over 2 kgm).  They were just right for letting me go down with my lungs full of air.  After doing each repair I could easily get back to the surface by pushing off the bottom (no rope required).  I would be very careful with anything much heavier.